# Получение данных из класса, после группировки

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Подскажите, как я могу получить данные после группировки в переменную
`parts` для дальнейшего использования? Вывести на экран могу через
`print(template['0_y'])`, если вызываю `print(parts)`, то выводит адрес в
памяти. Можно ли сделать вывод через `parts` как через `template['0_y']`?

```
Вывод print(template['0_y']):
    max    3575.0
    cen    1579.0
    min     700.0
    Name: 0_y, dtype: float64
    max     897.0
    cen    2842.0
    min    4412.0
    Name: 0_y, dtype: float64
    max     372.0
    cen     955.0
    min    2908.0
    Name: 0_y, dtype: float64
    max     460.0
    cen    1023.0
    min    1894.0
    Name: 0_y, dtype: float64


Вывод print(parts):

    datetime
    2019-07-22 10:00:00    <__main__.ThreeParts object at 0x000002477EEFA...
    2019-07-22 10:30:00    <__main__.ThreeParts object at 0x0000024700225...
    2019-07-22 11:00:00    <__main__.ThreeParts object at 0x0000024700749...
    2019-07-22 11:30:00    <__main__.ThreeParts object at 0x000002477EEF2...
    2019-07-22 12:00:00    <__main__.ThreeParts object at 0x000002477EF30...



class ThreeParts:
    def __init__(self, grouped_data):
        self.grouped_data = pd.DataFrame(grouped_data.sum(axis=1))

        self.buyers = grouped_data['vol']['B']
        self.sellers = grouped_data['vol']['S']

        self.out = self.get_outliers()
        self.top, self.centre, self.bottom = RangeCandle.chunk_candle(self.grouped_data)
        self.to_connect()

        self.lst = []

    def get_outliers(self):
        third_quantile_buyers = self.buyers.quantile([.90])
        third_quantile_sellers = self.sellers.quantile([.90])

        str_third_quantile_buyers = third_quantile_buyers.loc[.90]
        str_third_quantile_sellers = third_quantile_sellers.loc[.90]

        ten_percent_buyers = self.buyers[self.buyers >= str_third_quantile_buyers]
        ten_percent_sellers = self.sellers[self.sellers >= str_third_quantile_sellers]

        return pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([ten_percent_buyers, ten_percent_sellers], axis=1).sum(axis=1))

    def to_connect(self):
        max_vol = pd.merge(self.top, self.out, left_index=True, right_index=True).sum()
        cen_vol = pd.merge(self.centre, self.out, left_index=True, right_index=True).sum()
        min_vol = pd.merge(self.bottom, self.out, left_index=True, right_index=True).sum()

        template = pd.concat([max_vol, cen_vol, min_vol], keys=['max', 'cen', 'min']).unstack()
        return template['0_y']

parts = gd.groups_by_buyers_and_sellers().groupby(level='datetime').apply(lambda x: ThreeParts(x))
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Получить на выходе необходимо как через print(template['0_y'])